# Is there a presentation mode on mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

When watching a video, or making a presentation, is there an option or a tool to disable all screensaving, energy savings and all? Regardless of if the power is plugged, I'd like to keep the screen fully on.

I know I can manually adjust the settings everytime. But is there a "presentation" mode, in addition to "battery" and "power adapter" modes?
Or a tool to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best 3rd-party based solution for you is to use [Caffeine](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/caffeine.html).

> ***About Caffeine:***   A tiny program that
>   puts an icon in the right side of your
>   menu bar. Click it to prevent your Mac
>   from automatically going to sleep,
>   dimming the screen or starting screen
>   savers. Click it again to go back.
>   Hold down the Command key while
>   clicking to show the menu.

Comment: Caffeine does what the user requested, but I would suggest that the question was incomplete. When in presentation mode, you also want to make sure to either shut down the network, or shut down certain apps that use the network. You don't want an IM popping up mid-presentation...

Comment: true sometimes, but when your presentation uses the network, that can be problematic :)

Comment: While using Caffeine or a similar solution, you can stop notifications from popping up using the Do Not Disturb function built into OS X 10.8 and later. It's accessible from the notificaton centre found in the top-right: swipe down with two fingers to reveal the option.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing built-in to the OS, but [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) can be used to do what you want.

Comment: While not built-in, I can see how this could accomplish the task requested, and on a very wide range of MacOS versions.